# How to add enough zeros before a number in order to have six digits for this number using Python?

Tags: python

I have a huge list of numbers (each number is less or equal to 6 numbers) in my database like that :
90494
898333
898
13
etc..

And I would like to have them formatted like that, using python :
090494
898333
000898
000013
etc...

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard python interpolation with [C-style format modifiers](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) should work:

```
print "%06d" % number
```

---

Or, if you prefer [`.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples) described in [**PEP 3101**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) (most likely the future of string formatting in python):

```
print '{0:06d}'.format(1)
```

---

Or, if you're working with strings, you can use [`zfill`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.zfill):

```
print '1'.zfill(6)
```